# why am i getting 'i is not defined' error from a simple for loop in vue.js component script?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to taking an array, order that array by version, and then moving all versions that begin with 'ipad' to the end of the list.

snippet from single file vue.js component:

```
  computed: {
    orderedUsers: function () {
      let newArray = sortBy(this.jobs, 'version').reverse()
      for (i in newArray) {
        if (i.version.startsWith('iPad')) {
          newlist.push(newlist.splice(i, 1)[0]);
        }
      }
      return newArray
  },
```

error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?e832:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: i is not defined"
```

Not sure if this is a js question or a vue.js question

Comment: `for (i in newArray) {` should be `for (const i in newArray) {`.

Comment: `for (i in newArray) {` should be `for (const i of newArray) {`. `for...in` is for iterating over own properties of objects. For arrays, use `for...of`.

Comment: next question, *why am I getting 'newlist is not defined' error from a simple for loop in vue.js component script?* define your vars before use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add let i before using it in the for loop.
See example below.

```js
for (let i in newArray) {
  if (i.version.startsWith('iPad')) {
    newlist.push(newlist.splice(i, 1)[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with the original code.

1. The missing `const`/`let` on `i`
2. `in` loop should be `of`. Or maybe not. The following lines seem to assume that `i` is both the index and the entry.
3. `newlist` isn't defined.
4. It seems to be trying to mutate an array whilst iterating over it.

I think you're looking for something more like this.

```js
const newArray = sortBy(getData(), 'version').reverse()
const nonIPads = []
const iPads = []

for (const entry of newArray) {
  if (entry.version.startsWith('iPad')) {
    iPads.push(entry)
  } else {
    nonIPads.push(entry)
  }
}

const all = [...nonIPads, ...iPads]

console.log(all)

function sortBy(array, property) {
  return [...array].sort((a, b) => {
    const valueA = a[property]
    const valueB = b[property]

    if (valueA === valueB) {
      return 0
    }

    return valueA < valueB ? -1 : 1
  })
}

function getData() {
  return [
    {version: 'f'},
    {version: 'a'},
    {version: 'd'},
    {version: 'iPad 3'},
    {version: 'iPad 1'},
    {version: 'iPad 4'},
    {version: 'e'},
    {version: 'c'},
    {version: 'g'},
    {version: 'b'},
    {version: 'iPad 2'}
  ]
}
```