# Why am I getting Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined in this for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to sort an array by 'version' and then identify all string that begin with 'iPad'.

The following code does not log anything and returns an error.

```
orderedUsers: function () {
  let newarray = sortBy(this.jobs, 'version').reverse()
  for (let i in newarray) {
    if (i.version.startsWith('iPad')) {
      console.log(i.version);
    }
  }
  return newarray
```

error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
```

If I remove the for-loop and just put:

```
orderedUsers: function () {
  let newarray = sortBy(this.jobs, 'version').reverse()
  return newarray
```

The list is correctly sorted by version.  This makes me think the error is related to how I have written my for-loop or if statement.

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: What is `this.jobs`?

Comment: `for..in` is used to iterate over an object.  `i` in your loop is the index in the array.  The index doesn't have a version property.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in

Comment: I think I already covered this in my answer to your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674240/why-am-i-getting-i-is-not-defined-error-from-a-simple-for-loop-in-vue-js-compo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why am i getting 'i is not defined' error from a simple for loop in vue.js component script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674240/why-am-i-getting-i-is-not-defined-error-from-a-simple-for-loop-in-vue-js-compo)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29397769/621962

Answer (score -1):

The [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) construct is not doing what you think here. It is is designed to iterate over objects. So in this case it is treating `newArray` as an object but with the property names as the array indices. Arrays in Javascript are just objects with numeric property names. More specifically if you changed your code to:

```
for (let i in newarray) {
    if (i.version.startsWith('iPad')) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
```

You would clearly see the problem. `i` is a number and not a job object.

Comment: Why have you linked `for...in` to a book about Rust?

Comment: It was a mistake. Fixed it now. You're very quick though!

Comment: Thanks @Choc13 :)

Answer (score -1):

fix:

```
orderedUsers: function () {
  let newarray = sortBy(this.jobs, 'version').reverse()
  for (let i in newarray) {
    if (newarray[i].version.startsWith('iPad')) {
      console.log(newarray[i].version);
    }
  }
  return newarray
```

Comment: You should really mark Jack's answer as correct, rather than posting his solution again.

Comment: I used amy's initial comment to fix - but will mark jacks as correct if that's the same thing